# Static Map + HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas

I would like to use a static map image generated by google maps in a canvas element on my site. Since this image is loaded from an external source it will throw security warnings.

Whats is the best way to work around this? Will I need to cache every map on my server?

Answer (score 1):

Donot load any content from other domain in client side. Load the image at the server side using the network libraries in the server side technologies. For eg. in java, make a dedicated servlet to serve the image -

```
GoogleMapServlet extends HttpServlet {
void doGet(req, res) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("image/JPEG");
    //read the image from google using java.net package.
    //use imageio to write the image to response.outputstream.
    //return.
}
}
```

on the jsp page, use - `<img src="/images/GoogleMapServlet" alt=""/>`

If map never changes in future cache it.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example of something like this in node.js? Thanks for the help.